# “Try on some of them” or “Try some of them on”?

Tags: pronouns, phrasal-verbs

I’ve learnt that some phrasal verbs such as “pick up” or “try on” require us to put the object, especially when it is a pronoun, between the verb and preposition. Is it also possible to say “You should try some of them on before buying”? Or is it better to say “You should try on some of them”?

I’m looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/try-on-something

Comment: _Try some of them on_ is **much** more idiomatic to me.

Comment: I agree with Kate. But there's a lot of difference between 'Try them on' / *'Try on them' and 'Try some of them on' / 'Try on some of them', the last being grammatical but unusual. 'Try some of the jackets on' and 'Try on some of the jackets' are equally idiomatic and allow for different stresses.